# Joining tables to find corresponding columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I wanted to find the genre which had the highest average price and I did it like so:

```
SELECT MAX(MostExpensive) as HighestPrice, cdTitle
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(cdPrice) AS MostExpensive, cdTitle
    FROM `cd` GROUP BY cdGenre
) AS MostExpensiveAlbum
```

However, I soon realized that I would also need to get the name of the artist as well. I can easily add the columns in the `SELECT` statement but it happens so that the artist name column is in another table.

How can I possibly `JOIN` this table `cd` that I'm currently selecting from with the table `artist` and get the `artName` column so that it corresponds to the highest price.

**In short I want to find the artist name(s) with the highest price of album on average**

Here are my two tables: [image]

Comment: Please dont use screen shots for showing data.  You are better off building a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for rapid and accurate answers.

Comment: How does that matter?

Comment: it matters because it makes it easier to for us to help you find your answers. the best you can do is provide ddl+dml for sample data (I wouldn't suggest using a link to sql fiddle in a question as it suffers from a lot of downtime)

Comment: I'm sorry. Here's the SQL to create the tables. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xdaAeXb2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(MostExpensive) as HighestPrice, cdTitle,artName
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(cd.cdPrice) AS MostExpensive, cd.cdTitle,artist.artname
    FROM `cd` inner join 'artist' on cd.artId = artist.artId GROUP BY cdGenre
) AS MostExpensiveAlbum
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(AvgPrice) As MaximumAveragePrice, ArtName As ArtistName
FROM
(
    SELECT AVG(cdPrice) As AvgPrice, ArtName
    FROM cd 
    INNER JOIN artist ON(cd.ArtId = artist.ArtId)
    GROUP BY ArtName
) As AvgPricePerArtName 
GROUP BY ArtName
HAVING AvgPrice = MAX(AvgPrice)
```

**Note** Code was written directly here, didn't test it.

Comment: It's valid syntax but I need only the highest price and it currently returns all artists - albums.

Comment: the inner select has `SELECT AVG(cdPrice) As AvgPrice` Didn't you want the artist who's average cd price is the highest?

Comment: It renders it as a column thus returning an error. `Unknown column 'AvgPrice' in 'having clause'`

Comment: It is a column of the inner select. Try running the hole select on your database. (If you would have provided the ddl+dml) I could have tested my answer, now you see why that matters?)